# Unable to delete item from ReactiveCouchbaseRepository

Tags: java, groovy, spring-data-couchbase

Working on my first app using Spring data with Reactive Couchbase and having trouble with repository operations. I can create a User in my UserRepository and can retrieve it by id or name, but can't delete it. deleteAll() doesn't work either.

```
@N1qlPrimaryIndexed
@ViewIndexed(designDoc = "user")
interface UserRepository extends ReactiveCouchbaseRepository<User, String> {
    Flux<User> findByName(String name)
}

@Service
class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository

    Mono<User> save(User user) {
        return userRepository.save(user)
    }

    Mono<Void> delete(User user) {
        return userRepository.delete(user)
    }

    Mono<User> findById(String id) {
        return userRepository.findById(id)
    }

    Flux<User> findByName(String name) {
        return userRepository.findByName(name)
    }

}

class UserServiceTest extends ApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService

    @Test
    void testSave() {
        User user = new User(null, 'name')
        User savedUser = userService.save(user).block()

        List<User> allUsers = userRepository.findAll().collectList().block()
        assert allUsers.size() == 1

        userService.delete(allUsers.first())
        allUsers = userRepository.findAll().collectList().block()
        assert allUsers.size() == 0 // fails here
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply forgot to `subscribe()` (or `block()`) to the delete `Mono<Void>`